# Click Javascript button with cURL

Tags: javascript, forms, curl

I am trying to advance to next page with cURL.

This is the Javascript button I need to click:

```
<a href="javascript:goToPage(2)"> Next <img src="//prod25-taxlien.s3.amazonaws.com/images/general/next.png"></a>
```

I need to be able to go to next page and scrape the page and so on, page1 to page2 ....
Is there anyway to do this cURL?
Thanks

Comment: you can't "run" javascript with cURL because cURL doesn't know what javascript is

Comment: @JaromandaX: since the navigation is based on a client-side script, you have to actually execute the script. Or at least parse it to figure out what it would do if it were executed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - I'm perfectly aware of what needs to be done - cURL can't do it, because it has no concept of javascript at all, let alone able to execute or parse javascript

Comment: So, how can I navigate to next page using php? is there anyway I can create an url somehow from this javascript button to be able to go to the next page. Do you guys need anything else to help me out. I am sorry for the ignorance. Thanks